# Dialog Box will not show

Tags: java, android

I created an AlertDialogFragment class and I am trying to show it from another class with the following code but I keep getting an error to change the type from FragmentTranscation to FragmentManager.  If I change it to FragmentManager, I get a message to change to FragmentTranscation, whenever I change to FragmentTranscation, I get a message to change to FragmentManager:

Here is the code to show the alertDialog:

```
FragmentTransaction ft= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
AlertDialogFragment newFragment= new AlertDialogFragment();
newFragment.show(ft, "alertDialog");
```

Here is the code for the class:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder
    = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Staying in Touch With The Ones You Love");
    builder.setTitle("Togetherness");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

Comment: check this tutorial--> http://vinaygopinath.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/alertdialog-using-fragment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a fragment, you need to either replace an existing fragment or add a new one to an existing view.

Edit: Sorry, didn't notice it was a dialog fragment.
Use this:

```
// DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
// in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
// dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("alertDialog");
if (prev != null) {
    ft.remove(prev);
}
ft.addToBackStack(null);

// Create and show the dialog.
newFragment.show(ft, "alertDialog");
```

And take a look at examples here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Remember that fragments were introduced in API level 11. If you're using an older API level, follow the instructions here to use the Support Library for all your fragment stuff (I see your `DialogFragment` is already inheriting from support library `FragmentDialog`)

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```